# how to make a JDialog never on top (within one application, not system-wide)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog

I have a GUI with several JDialogs, 2 or 3 of which are "basic" big ones, and should therefore be "never on top" of others (small ones).

I think using "always on top" on the other JDialog would be a solution, but is not exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

any tip welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 1.6, maybe playing around with [ModalityType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) and [ModalExclusionType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalExclusionType.html) will help you. Note that modalitytype and modalexclusiontype are only available in 1.6 onwards

Comment: ModalityType implies some level of blocking, however my dialogs are modeless, the issue is not with modality: the dialogs should not be blocking in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your large JDialogs might need to be JFrames instead.

Another option:  Use a JDesktopPane and use JInternalFrame.

Third option: Use a Layered Panes to control the ordering of items.

Comment: **using JFrames** does not work. the "small" dialogs that I would create would only be associated with ONE of the 3 JFrames, so would be "always on top" of only this JFrame, not the others. **JDesktopPane** is a valid option, but it defeats the idea of using only JDialog (it adds one "encompassing" JFrame). **Layered Panes**, I think it can't be used like this. JDialogs can't be added to a Layered pane (although the closest thing wo this would be the JDesktopPane). after some research, Z-ordering of JDialogs appears not to be well supported by Java, as it's mostly platform-dependant.